# I am unable to create a table in MySQL (Error 1005)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table `users` however I am getting the error "Unable to create table" when running the query with MySQL Workbench and also PHPMyAdmin. I appear to be getting the error on where it says:

store   VARCHAR(5),

```
CREATE TABLE store
(
    id          INT                 NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    short_name  VARCHAR(5)                      NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    address1    VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    address2    VARCHAR(20),
    city        VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    state       VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    zip         VARCHAR(10)                     NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(15)                     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT store_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id          INT                     NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname       VARCHAR(35)                     NOT NULL,
    lname       VARCHAR(35)                     NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(60),        
    address1    VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    address2    VARCHAR(20),
    city        VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    state       VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    zip         VARCHAR(10)                     NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(15),
    email       VARCHAR(90),
    store       VARCHAR(5),
    admin       TINYINT             DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,
    mail_list   TINYINT             DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,
    active      TINYINT             DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_fk FOREIGN KEY (store)
        REFERENCES store (short_name)
        ON DELETE   SET NULL
        ON UPDATE   CASCADE
);
```

The store table is added successfully. It is only when I attempt to create the users table that I get the errors.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column referenced in a foreign key needs to be indexed. So you need to add an index on `store.short_name` to allow it to be referenced in the `users_fk` foreign key.